# Connection to MSAccess DB unable to perform more than one query

Tags: ms-access, iis, windows-7, asp-classic, odbc

I'm setting up my first locally hosted website on a new machine in a long time and to be honest am not very familiar with all the manual settings that get configured now. My last set up was on a Windows XP box and it seemed to "just work" when I enabled IIS. Not so this time.

My latest issues is with connecting to a MSAccess DB. I have a VERY BASIC page with a form that contains 1 input. I check the DB to make sure it doesn't already contain the value and if not, then write the value to the DB. I get the following error:

```
Provider error '80004005'
Unspecified error
/trips/admin_add_hotel.asp, line 22
```

I've researched online and everything seems to point to it being a permissions issue. However, I can remove the second portion of the code (the writing) and the page will return fine. If I try to run the page again or refresh, I'll then get the error. This to me says the user has read access. Now, I can wait a little bit and remove the first portion of the code and just write to the DB and it will work fine. Again, to me signifying that the user has write access. However, if I try to run it again... same error.

Here's the ASP code:

```
<!--#include file="includefile.asp"-->
<%
if Request("action") = "submit" then
    'make sure hotel name is filled in
    if Request("fhotel") <> "" then
        fhotel = Request("fhotel")

        'make sure hotel doesn't already exist in DB
        sql = "SELECT hotel_id FROM hotels WHERE hotel_name = '" & Replace(fhotel, "'", "''") & "'"
        RS.Open sql, ConnectString
            if NOT RS.EOF then
                Session("msg") = "Hotel already exists"
            End if
        RS.Close

        'add hotel to DB
        if Session("msg") = "" then
            sql = "INSERT INTO hotels (hotel_name) VALUES ('" & Replace(fhotel, "'", "''") & "')"

            Conn.Open ConnectString
            Conn.Execute sql
            Conn.Close

            Session("msg") = "Hotel added successfully"
            fhotel = ""
        End if
    Else
        Session("msg") = "Hotel left blank"
    End if

    Set RS = Nothing
    Set Conn = Nothing

End if
%>
```

My include file is:

```
<%  
ConnectString = "DSN=ConnectionDSN; Uid=username; Pwd=password"

Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
%>
```

My DB has 1 table with two columns:

- hotel_id [AUTONUMBER]
- hotel_name [TEXT (255)]

Here are my system details:

- Windows 7 Pro 64-bit (although connections have been set up for 32-bit based on what I've found online)
- IIS 7.5

Just to make sure it wasn't a permissions issue, I've temporarily allowed the 'Everyone' user full access to that folder.

Any help is appreciated. I believe this is the last hurdle I have to get thing fully up and running.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to have permission to create a lock file *.ldb in the folder your database resides in.  Probably you don't have create-file permission in that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- 32bit vs 64bits: make absolutely sure that your application is set explicitly to x86, not AnyCPU. Also make sure that if you are using the newer `.accdb` you have the Access Database Engine drivers installed.
- Permissions: as Dan Matheus said, make sur that the process under which IIS runs has write permission to the folder. It may not be enough that you set it to *Everyone*, make sure that your web app can actually create a file in that folder (test this assumption in your code).
- Make sure your connection string for the Access file explicitly mentions shared access, and not exclusive access, otherwise, if different processes have the
- Keep a connection to the database open all the time to avoid issues with the quick creation/deletion of the lock file.
  The Jet/ACE database driver needs to create the lock file every time you access the file (if it is in shared mode). Issues will arise when your app quickly access/releases the database file and the lock file is created/deleted too often.
  First it will greatly slow down your performance, and second you will get strange errors.
  Just keep a connection open to the database and close it when your app shutdowns.

For more information about the points above, see this:

- [Intermittent “System resource exceeded” exception for OleDB connection to Microsoft Access data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484298/intermittent-system-resource-exceeded-exception-for-oledb-connection-to-micros/13485162#13485162)