# Issue while executing .net 4.5 framework build assemblies on .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-framework-version

I have a windows service that is build targeting .net framework 4. It is a 32 bit application. It uses a MS Access database at the back end for scheduling. At the same time it interface with lot of RDBMS. This has been in use since last 7 years and more than 8000 installs have being successfully running. Recently I had to support interfacing one RDBMS. The native .net provider for this database is available only with .net framework 4.5.
So to be compatible with this newer database, I compiled my service against 4.5. I wend ahead with this change, as I was able to run this application on my development machine which does not have 4.5 installed. I checked this as 8000 machines where we already have this installed might not have 4.5 installed and would create problems. But as it worked on my development machine, I went ahead with the change.

After the updates were pushed, we started getting OleDbException "System resources exceeded" while querying underlying MS Access database. NOTE : The machine where we encountered the above exception are mostly using windows server OS(2008, 2012) and do not have 4.5 installed. The code where we are encountering this exception has not been changed for years. Also where we have encountered this issue we are not actually interfacing with the newer  database.

Also apart from the newer database provider assembly that is compiled against 4.5 I am not using any 4.5 specific issue.

So I suspect this issue is caused by migration to 4.5??

Comment: Assuming you didn't change anything else, it certainly appears that way.

Comment: A Google search for `oledbexception system resource exceeded` reveals [this hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2726928/-system-resource-exceeded-error-message-when-you-perform-a-query-in-ac) and [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/155959/). Have you tried either of these? For future reference, search for the exact error message on Google to see if there are any clues before asking a question here.

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984339/system-data-oledb-oledbexception-system-resource-exceeded) SO question.

Comment: “But as it worked on my development machine, I went ahead with the change.” You bite yourself. You will have to install .NET Framework 4.5 on all machines if you use even a single assembly relying on it. Anyway Microsoft requires all applications to be on **.NET Framework 4.5.2 and above** today.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs NightOwl888. However [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155959/oledbexception-system-resources-exceeded) question does not answer my question. I have already added code to use using even if I am working in a while loop and opening connection every 5 seconds. The question is more about, why this exception only after moving to .net framework 4.5.